# Frequency Queries HackerRank

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have been solving this question: [Frequency Queries](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/frequency-queries/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps), and somehow struggling in getting the code work for **All Time out cases**, which is in my case is 5 only. All those time out case, no wrong answers.

I have this solution, in which I am only using **DefaultDict**, and I am sure, it should work for cases greater than **10^9**, but getting timeout every time.

> 1. Why my code is inefficient?
> 2. How is your code better than my solution?

**My Code:**

```
d = defaultdict(int)
q = int(input().strip())

for _ in range(q):
  op , data = (map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
  if op == 1:
      d[data] += 1
  elif op == 2:
      if data in d:
         d[data] -= 1
      d[data] = 0 if d[data] < 0 else d[data]
  elif op == 3:
      print (1 if data in d.values() else 0)
```

I cannot think best solution more than this. My solution is `O(n)`, please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> print (1 if data in d.values() else 0)

Problem lies here d.values() is not a good way to check if given value is in the dictionary. 
Internally Python use Hash function for the *KEY* not for the *VALUE* mapped on that *KEY*. So average case operations may work here in O(1) if you are deleting, updating and inserting *VALUES* by *KEY*. But worst case complexity can be O(N) which can be rare but not ignorable. So your solution is not O(N)

Try something with two dictionaries one for frequency and one for count of frequency 
Here is what i tried using two maps in C++

```
    map<int,int> count,freq_count;
    ll i,j,k,n,m,mask,x;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>x>>m;
        if(x==1){
            if(count.find(m)!=count.end()){
                freq_count[count[m]]--;
                if(freq_count[count[m]] == 0)
                    freq_count.remove(count[m]);
            }
            count[m]++;
            frefreq_count[count[m]]++;
        } else if(x==2) {
            freq_count[count[m]]--;
            if(freq_count[count[m]] == 0)
                freq_count.remove(count[m]);
            if(count[m]==0)
                count.remove(m);

        } else {
            if(freq_count.find(m)!= freq_count.end()){
                cout<<"1\n";
            }
            else{
                count<<"0\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I know what is the complexity of my problem then. I thought that the loop is the one which is taking highest complexity, hence `O(n)`. Plus your code is very difficult to understand, please comment on your code so that I can understand. Don't you think, your program will take more space?

Comment: d.values() is of dictionary size complexity because you are checking if data exist in values of dictionary. Just once print d.values() and check it prints whole values list. You can not exactly calculate complexity when you are dealing with hashes because of collisions, python internally use hashes in dict implementation. We can not do all insert ,delete and update operation in O(1). we have to do some preprocessing for that which python is doing for you and C++ in my code.